# Weird Java Webstart JNLP exception

Tags: java, parsing, jnlp, java-web-start

I am having a java webstart app which uses a simple JNLP.
Recently I am having wierd problems when launching it. I never had this problem before and I am pretty sure none of the content got modified either :(
I get this error when trying to launch this app.

```
WARNING: <> tag is not closed correctly Exception parsing xml at line 33
at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensionsHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.downloadExtensions(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As you can see its not giving which tag has the problem. As far as I can see; there is no problem with line 33.
it has a simple tag `<argument>session_token_here</argument>`

Update:
This is the JNLP file;

```
  <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://MASKHOST:5467/"
 href="https://MASKHOST:5467/myjnlp.jnlp?session=rO0ABXNyADpjb20ud2lseS5pbnRyb3Njb3BlLnNwZWMuc2VydmVyLmJlYW5zLnNlc3Npb24uU2Vzc2lvblRva2Vu9ef0qNvv5yoMAAB4cHNyADBjb20ud2lseS5pc2VuZ2FyZC5wb3N0b2ZmaWNlLlBvc3RPZmZpY2VTcGVjaWZpZXL69Qzv1IsXcgwAAHhwdw4ABUxvY2FsAAVMb2NhbHh3CDWNLwuY3RbfeA%3d%3d&myauth=true">
 <information>
     <title>App Title</title>
     <vendor>Company</vendor>
     <homepage href="null"/>
     <description>Product Name</description>
     <icon href="https://MASKHOST:5467/images/logo.png"
 kind="default"/>   </information>   <security>
     <all-permissions/>   </security>   <update check="timeout"
 policy="always"/>   <resources>
     <jar
 href="https://MASKHOST:5467/product/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20080819.jar"
 download="eager" main="false"/>
     <extension href="https://MASKHOST:5467/jnlp/productplugins.jsp"
 name="Component name"/>
     <extension href="https://MASKHOST:5467/jnlp/platformplugins.jsp"
 name="Core Plugins"/>
     <property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home/Application
 Data/company/product/component"/>
     <property name="osgi.configuration.area"
 value="@user.home/Application Data/company/product/component"/>
     <property name="eclipse.product" value="osgiproductname"/>
     <java java-vm-args="-Xms64m -Xmx256m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
 href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
 version="1.6*&1.6.0_05+"/>
     <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>   </resources> 
 <application-desc
 main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain">
     <argument>-noexit</argument>
     <argument>-clean</argument>
     <argument>-loginhost</argument>
     <argument>MASKHOST</argument>
     <argument>-loginport</argument>
     <argument>6785</argument>
     <argument>-session</argument>

 <argument>rO0ABXNyADpjb20ud2lseS5pbnRyb3Njb3BlLnNwZWMuc2VydmVyLmJlYW5zLnNlc3Npb24uU2Vzc2lvblRva2Vu9ef0qNvv5yoMAAB4cHNyADBjb20ud2lseS5pc2VuZ2FyZC5wb3N0b2ZmaWNlLlBvc3RPZmZpY2VTcGVjaWZpZXL69Qzv1IsXcgwAAHhwdw4ABUxvY2FsAAVMb2NhbHh3CDWNLwuY3RbfeA==</argument>
     <argument>-myauth</argument>
     <argument>true</argument>
   </application-desc>
 </jnlp>
```

Any help or pointers to proceed further is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your JNLP file

Comment: Would You mind pasting the JNLP content?

Comment: Is this the full `XML` content?

Comment: I would still recommend looking at Janela. It's a very useful app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<extension href="https://MASKHOST:5467/jnlp/productplugins.jsp"
 name="Component name/>
```

Should be..

```
<extension href="https://MASKHOST:5467/jnlp/productplugins.jsp"
 name="Component name"/>
```

But check the JNLP usig JaNeLA and fix any errors identified.

Comment: I was trying to remove the names and references :D lol. Yeah I have a quote in actual file. Thank you!

Comment: Since even attributes or values might contain invalid characters that then make the JNLP invalid and the launch fail, I will have nothing further to do with questions that present a 'privatized' or 'sanitized' JNLP.  Make sure you validate the **actual** JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Sorry to change the names; I dont have options. But thanks; I found the problem starting from here. The first extension jsp was not returning and instead somehow homepage was returning. Fixed it and working as a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Re the names - that's the way it goes sometimes.  Glad to hear you got it sorted.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
<java java-vm-args="-Xms64m -Xmx256m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6*&1.6.0_05+"/>
```

has an embedded `&` which should be escaped like this:

```
<java java-vm-args="-Xms64m -Xmx256m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6*&amp;1.6.0_05+"/>
```

There is an unescaped `&` on the first line also.

The following line is missing a closing double quote:

```
 <extension href="https://MASKHOST:5467/jnlp/productplugins.jsp" name="Component name/>
```

but that may be a redaction typo.

Comment: I noticed the first one and changed it but was still getting error. I did not notice the second one. I will try changing and running it. (not near that machine now). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any JNLP file, I can suggest using the [Janela](http://pscode.org/janela/) JNLP validator tool

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've got an xml-comment or hanging quote character `"` or something?